# Zipios error on Mac 10.9 using Qt 5.4 and Clang(64 bit)

Tags: c++, macos, qt, clang

I am trying to use Zipios++(v2.1.0) C++ library for zipping files on Mac 10.9. Below is my code to zip a collection of files into an archive.

```
zipios::ZipFile zf;
zipios::DirectoryCollection dirCollection(<folder with all files>);
zipios::DirectoryCollection finalCollection;

zipios::FileEntry::vector_t files = dirCollection.entries();

// selecting only the necessary files
for(auto it = files.begin(); it != files.end(); ++it)
{
    // THIS IS WHERE I GET AN ERROR
    zipios::DirectoryEntry dirEntry = dynamic_cast<zipios::DirectoryEntry>(**it);
    if(arrFiles.contains(QString::fromStdString(dirEntry.getFileName())))
        finalCollection.addEntry(*(*it));
}

std::filebuf fb;
fb.open (strFileName.toStdString(), std::ios::out);
std::ostream os(&fb);
zf.saveCollectionToArchive(os, finalCollection);
fb.close();
zf.close();
```

I need to iterate the files inside the folder and if they match my list of files to be included I add them to `finalCollection` for archiving. But I am not able to cast it properly. Does anyone have any sample code for zipping multiple files to one file using Zipios? Any advice on the below code will be helpful. Thanks.

UPDATE:
I was able to fix the error. Below code changes worked for me-

```
for(auto entry(files.begin()); entry != files.end(); ++entry)
{
    if(!(*entry)->isDirectory())
    {
      if(arrFiles.contains(QString::fromStdString((*entry)->getFileName())))
        finalCollection.addEntry(*(*entry));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post it as an answer instead

Comment: Answer my own question? Is that allowed, I was not aware of that :P

Comment: Sure it is :) (some even ask almost impossible question just to provide the answer!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the error. Below code changes worked for me-

```
for(auto entry(files.begin()); entry != files.end(); ++entry)
{
    if(!(*entry)->isDirectory())
    {
      if(arrFiles.contains(QString::fromStdString((*entry)->getFileName())))
        finalCollection.addEntry(*(*entry));
    }
}
```

The issue was I was not dereferencing the pointers properly, a good look at the zipios code gave some ideas and this is what worked!

Comment: You may now explain what was the benefit, how the changes fixed your solution, what was the error... But it's up to you :)